# sapui5 sap.ui.unified.Calendar how can we remove the Selected SpecialDate color from Calendar

Tags: sapui5

Im facing an issue in **sap.ui.unified.Calendar**, If i select any particular special date and cancel that selected date, color should get removed(Green color should get removed) from the calendar. Here im able to remove that from backend but it is not reflected in the UI. But if i reload the application it is getting removed.

[image]

In the above screenshot if you see, After selecting Date 23rd and if i click on "Cancel", an Odata service is getting called and Selected date is getting removed. But it is not reflecting in UI. But if i reload the app then im seeing the expected behavior. But i want that behavior immediately when i click on Cancel.Here im just calling an Odata service to cancel the selected Dates.

Below is the code to display the colors in calendar..

```
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                                        //oRefDate.setDate(i);
                                        var oRefDate = new Date(data.results[i].Reqdate);
                                        var sType = "";
                                        if (data.results[i].Legendid == "GROUP_LEVEL1") {
                                            sType = "Type01";
                                        } else if (data.results[i].Legendid == "BADVALUE_LIGHT") {
                                            sType = "Type02";
                                        } else if (data.results[i].Legendid == "NEGATIVE") {
                                            sType = "Type03";
                                        } else if (data.results[i].Legendid == "KEY_MEDIUM") {
                                            sType = "Type04";
                                        } else if (data.results[i].Legendid == "GOODVALUE_DARK") {
                                            sType = "Type02";
                                        }
                                        oCal1.addSpecialDate(new sap.ui.unified.DateTypeRange({
                                            startDate: new Date(oRefDate),
                                            type: sType,
                                            tooltip: data.results[i].Tooltip
                                        }));

                                    }
```

Can some one please help me to fix this issue..

Comment: Can you share the code also in the question?

Comment: I have added the code. Can you please check and help me

Comment: The call which goes back to oData shall send a following up "GET". You need to then execute the above logic there.

try refreshing the model : this.getView().getModel().refresh()
or
try placing the coloring logic inside of another method which is called after GET call is made.

Comment: im going to execute the same logic here..If im trying to do refresh() or call the same service, Selected color is getting removed in backend. But in UI it is not getting removed. If i reload the page then i can see the removal of color. Im trying with both removeSpecialDate() and removeSelectedDate() but nothing is getting worked

Comment: Didi u try this.getView().getModel().refresh(true)  or this.getView().getModel().updateBindings(true) ???

Comment: @I.B.N. im not using model here. Im directly binding the calendar with "id" (oCal1). Here how can i achieve that?

Comment: So you have to update de binding manually after call the odata.

Comment: As I said above, after Update call is finished which updates the data in backend a GET call is made which will get the data. 

In this case, UI elements will automatically show latest updated data if:
* you are using two way binding i.e binding the controls with the model

Otherwise, you need to update the control binding manually.

Comment: @NandanChaturvedi  im updating the binding manually by calling the same GET Service in the backend. But color is not getting removed. But if i reloadl, then the same GET Service is getting called and color is getting removed and behaving as expected. Im not understanding what is wrong :(

Comment: as another try, can you try adding this code in method "onAfterRendering"

Comment: my luck is very bad..it is still not working :(